# How should I model large bodies of textual content in a django app?

Tags: python, django, search, model, storage

This is a question about best-practice for modelling a Django app. The project is a blog which will present articles written in something similar to Markdown or RST.

I've checked out a few tutorials to give me some sort of starting point and so far they all store the body of the article in the model. This seems wrong: my understanding of modern database engines isn't the best but storing textfields of arbitrary lengths can't be good for performance.

Three alternatives present themselves:

1. Limit the article model to metadata and create a separate model to
   store the body of an article. At least only one table is a mess!
2. Limit the article model to metadata and store the article body as a
   static file.
3. Ask someone with more experience. Maybe storing the body in the model
   isn't so bad after all... at least it's easily searchable!

How should I model this app? How would you make your solution searchable?

Comment: For those here from Google, here's the simplest blog tutorial I found: http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/starting-your-application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the body of the post in the database shouldn't be an issue. Most blog engines take this approach. It'll be faster than storing it in a separate model (if it's in a separate model, you'd have to do a JOIN to get the body), and likely faster than storing it as a file on the file system. You're not using the body as a primary key, so the length doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely store relatively large bodies of text in database. If you mean by performance there are two angles:

1. Searching. You should not do then free form searches in database. You may use specific features of ElasticSearch-like tools.
2. Serving large bodies of text. Unavoidable, naturally, if you want to present it, however you can use GZIP compression that will reduce the bandwidth drastically.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice about ElasticSearch-like tools.